# Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\abc.zip

Tags: c#, jenkins, amazon-s3, glob, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to upload my artifacts to S3 Bucket from my Windows Machine using s3 Plugin of Jenkins. Getting error

> Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CD Gateway API\publish.zip.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Deploy Plugin failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260278/jenkins-deploy-plugin-failing)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731329/jenkins-attachments-what-is-the-syntax